# Athena Parallel Unloads to the same location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Typically when I run an `UNLOAD` query in Amamzon Athena to a directory that already has files in it, the query will error out as intended.

However, in my use case, the same UNLOAD query can be called in parallel by two different threads to the same location. When run in parallel, Athena allows both queries to execute and the output of both queries is dumped to the same directory. This causes duplicate rows to be dumped.

Is there a way to ensure that only one of the two query can successfully execute?

For example:

Thread A:

```
UNLOAD (
<query>
)
TO '<s3 path>'
WITH (format = 'PARQUET', compression = 'SNAPPY')
```

Thread B:

```
UNLOAD (
<query>
)
TO '<s3 path>'
WITH (format = 'PARQUET', compression = 'SNAPPY')
```

Each query results in 72 rows, but when two threads run the same query. 144 results are in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to ensure that only one query succeeds in your example, but you may switch from UNLOAD to [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html), if possible. Both queries will try to create the same table, which is not possible and will error out. But, from succeeded query you'll get output files in your S3 location.

One of those queries will succeed, while the other will get the following error:

> HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS: Target directory for table

The problem with the CTAS approach is that you'll have to drop the table, so you don't clutter Athena DB you're using.